# Programmatically get Current Playing YouTube Video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to authenticate user Google account and fetch currently playing video ID, title or URL. I looked into [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs) and wasn't able to find any relevant endpoint. Is it possible to do the same?

Inspiration: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/get-the-users-currently-playing-track/

Comment: As far as I know, YouTube Data API v3 does not have any such endpoint.

Comment: You have to *somehow* get the YouTube user history - not easy and not available through YouTube API's, AFAIK.