# Can I access the youtube player from external android app and get currently playing video ID and exact playing position?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

Do you know, whether it is possible to access the YouTube player on a mobile phone from a self-developed android/iPhone App? In order to get the information, which video the user currently watches, and also the exact time-stamp of the played video at that moment? Is this possible?
Of course, assuming that the user would have explicitly allowed accessing this information before.
Or is Youtube running too much in its own “sandbox” and not accessible from other apps?

I was reading e.g.
[Programmatically get Current Playing YouTube Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62949345/programmatically-get-current-playing-youtube-video)
including the answers, and am afraid that this is not possible - since I would need even more: the playing position.

If such external access of the youtube player is not possible, what could be an alternative? To provide an own, newly programmed, standalone youtube player within our app, which then would have no problems accessing such information? If so, does any one have a recommendation for a tool / tutorial that could show me, how to build such an app?

I appreciate any hints and comments!
Best regards,
Matthias